# can we add merge --no ff in .gitattributes file without modifying gitconfigs

Tags: git, github, tfs, merge

We are using `TFS-Git` as our source control . We are following git branching workflow and pull requests to merge our code to stable branches.

We recently observed that pull-request merges on TFS are doing "git merge" by default , and we were been expecting a "git merge --no-ff" on each pull request merge.

- I am looking for a workaround for adding "--no-ff" to pull request merges without modifying git default configs under TFS.
- I am looking for an option where I can add this in a file ( eg .gitattributes) and checkin to our repositories that will override default gitconfigs only on that branch/repository.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add merge --no ff in .gitattributes, as `gitattributes` file is a simple text file that gives attributes to pathnames. The effect is certain operations by Git can be influenced by assigning particular attributes to a path.

While the Git configuration file contains a number of variables that affect the Git commands' behavior. You still need to set `pull.ff` to `false` in configuration file.